# Access to only a part of a Json value

Tags: json, react-native

I want to take a part of JSON element.
I have JSON format like

```
{  
   "reservation":[  
      {  
         "resa":"1902211200-1802211330"
      },
      {  
         "resa":"1902221130-1902221230"
      }
   ]
}
```

and for each reservation I want to only have access to the 4 last values - so here **1330** for the first resa and **1230** for the second

```
<View>
    <FlatList
      data= {this.state.JsonList}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.resa}.substring(17, 20)</Text>}
                  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} />
</View>
```

substring doesn't work and displays the word substring but I can't find how to do it. Can you tell me how I can do display only a part of the JSON value?

Comment: The `.substring(....)` should also appear within the `}`: move it in there:`{item.resa.substring(17, 20)}`. Note that `.slice(-4)` might be more practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should contain the full function with in the `{}` if you want it to calculate the substring correctly. Anything outside the `{}` will just be rendered as a string.

```
<Text>{item.resa.substring(17, 21)}</Text>
```

You will also want to change it so that you are including the last character in the string. Otherwise if you use `substring(17, 20)` then you will only get `133` instead of `1330` so use `substring(17, 21)`

```js
let item = { resa: "1902211200-1802211330" }

console.log(item.resa.substring(17,20)) // 133
console.log(item.resa.substring(17,21)) // 1330
console.log(item.resa.substring(item.resa.length-4)) // you could use the length to calculate the substring
console.log(item.resa.slice(-4)) // you could always use slice
```

Comment: if you need last four always then try this `item.resa.slice(-4)`